# C# How to use EF core in an action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to validate the user before enter the specific action, so I choose to use the custom attribute.

```
 public class UserValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public UserValidationAttribute()
        {
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            string objectId = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type.ToLower() == ClaimType.ObjectIdentifier.ToLower())?.Value;

            //Need to read the DB and validate the users
            {

            }
        }
```

```
//Need to read the DB and validate the users
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(objectId))
{
   DBContext dbContext = new DBContext();

   var user = dbContext.UserB2cs.FirstOrDefault(r => r.B2cobjectId == objectId)?.User;
}
```

`DBContext dbContext = new DBContext();`

There is an error here:"Unhandled Exception occured. Unable to process the request. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

I tried to solve that but failed, please help to provide some advices.

Comment: Inject the DbContext the same way you would for a controller action. The error occurs because the hard-coded *and leaking* `new DBContext()` will use whatever hard-coded driver and connection string is used in `OnConfiguring`, not what you specified through `AddDbContext`

Comment: On the other hand, `need to read the DB and validate the users` that's the job of ASP.NET Identity, which already stores users in the database and has *already* verified them before any custom action filter is called

Comment: Your `DbContext` instance is getting the wrong connection string.